# Can someone tell me the steps to make RIS connection with modality emulator using asp.net windows form?

Tags: c#, connection, modality

I have been trying to make a windows form using asp.net but unfortunately I cannot establish a connection with Modality emulator DVTK. I have tried all steps but I cannot find any useful documentation or instruction guide.
Can anyone please help me with this?

I tried connecting modality emulator with my laptop using asp.net windows form. I tried to ping RIS (which is successful) but I don't know how to connect my laptop with emulator

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.